# Chainable classes with common parent class

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

I am trying to create a structure where i can stack multiple classes that extend the same parent class. by stacking I mean something like stacking `then` in the following example :

```
  promise.then(
      data=>{
        return promise;
      }
  ).then(
      data=>{
        return promise;
      }
  ).then(
      ....
  )
```

where the second `data`is the one resolved by the first returned promise.

for my case I have an `operation` class which have multiple child classes `createUser`, `sendEmail` and `generateConfig`. and I want to be able to stack those the following way :

```
let generateConfigREturnedValue = createUser(null, usercreationInput)

  .sendEmail(createUSerReturnedValue, sendEmailInput)

  .generateConfig(sendEmailReturnedValue, generateConfigInput)

  .finish();
```

I want to be able to stack, the above way, any class that extends the operation parent class.

**Note :** The `ReturnedValue` arguments are not passed explicitly that way but rather that is how they will be passed and received by the nextInline operation.

**EDIT:**

So the parent `operation` class would have an abstract method called `execute` which will be automatically called wen chaining the child classes ( the child class will have its main code in that method ). So technically the class chaining I am talking about is chaining of the `execute` methods of each class while passing the arguments.

**My thoughts :**

1. Adding all the child operations to the prototype of each of the child operations, thus all child operations will have each other to call. After that I need to setup the, under the hood, argument passing from an operation to an other.
2. extending the prototype attribute lookup on the parent `operation` class to include fetching objects using their names from a dependency container ( something like [awilix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/awilix) )

is what I want to do is implementable and which is the best thought of the couple above ?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by "stack" a class or what this has to do with a prototype or a class.  You don't show any code that has anything to do with classes.  Are you just trying to implement `a().b().c()`?  FYI, that's called a "fluent interface" in case you want to search on it.  A derived class can call it's parent method with `super.method()` if that has anything to do with what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks, for the information I did need that name to look for. for the classe part, I still don't know how to implement any aspect of it. Yes I want to implement `a().b().c()` where each of a, b and c are classes that extend a common class. So it is a bit more complicated than, let's say, the builder pattern

Comment: the prototype part is just an idea on how to achieve the fluent interface

Comment: Still doesn't make sense.  You don't call classes with `a().b().c()`.  You call functions or perhaps methods.

Comment: Neither of those are `class`es. The term you are looking for is **method chaining**. It has nothing to do with prototypes or inheritance.

Comment: Well, a fluent interface with methods is implemented by just returning `this` from your method so you can chain them and whatever you return from the previous method will be passed to the next method in the chain, but I have no idea what that has to do with your multiple classes or your promise example.

Comment: @jfriend00 the idea is that I don't want to do the method chaining because I don't have a

Comment: @jfriend00 the idea is that I don't want to do the method chaining because I already have the `operation` structure and I want to keep using it, instead of changing to a method chaining or builder pattern. Second my goal is to chain all the classes that extend the parent `operation` class not just specific methods within a class. I edited some code of the existing classes I want to use.

Comment: The wording you're using has us confused.  You cannot chain a ***class***.  You chain a method or a function.  If you want all the methods on a class to be chained, then you working in making all the methods work that way.  You don't chain a class.  It's also not very feasible to pass a value from one method to another when chaining.  You would have to store whatever state you want to go from one method to the next in the object itself and pick it up from there in the next method in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if your functions perform asynchronous actions in order to get a result, you cannot expect your `.finish()` call to return that final result *synchronously*. The best you can hope for is a promise from `.finish()`.

I would suggest to do all the hard work in the `finish` method, and let all other methods just collect the input data.

I assume you have the core asynchronous functions already available, and I will refer to them via the `api` object:

```
class Chain {
    createUser(userCreationInput) {
        this.userCreationInput = userCreationInput;
        return this;
    }
    sendEmail: function(sendEmailInput) {
        this.sendEmailInput = sendEmailInput;
        return this;
    }
    generateConfig(generateConfigInput) {
        this.generateConfigInput = generateConfigInput;
        return this;
    }
    async finish() {
        let createUserReturnedValue = await api.createUser(null, this.userCreationInput);
        let sendEmailReturnedValue = await api.sendEmail(createUserReturnedValue, this.sendEmailInput);
        return api.generateConfig(sendEmailReturnedValue, this.generateConfigInput);
    }
}

let generateConfigReturnedValue = await new Chain()
    .createUser(usercreationInput)
    .sendEmail(sendEmailInput)
    .generateConfig(generateConfigInput)
    .finish();
```

Obviously the `await` should be used in an `async` function context.

This is just focussing on core functionality. You would have to add checks that all information is provided when `finish` is called, deal with error handling, ...etc.

If you don't like the `new Chain()` part in the expression, then you could define these three methods also as global functions and let those return a new instance of `Chain`. It's a choice between littering the global namespace or having the extra `new Chain()`.

A middle ground would be to define the functions also as static methods -- again, returning a new instance of `Chain`. Then the expression would be:

```
let x = Chain.createUser(usercreationInput). // ...etc
```